# NetBeans don't see class Matcher of java.util.regex

Tags: java, regex, netbeans, nashorn

Java 8.111, NetBeans IDE 8.2, no Maven.

NetBeans don't see class `Matcher` of `java.util.regex`. Instead of this IDE proposes `jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.regexp.joni.Matcher`. 
How to fix the error? Сan not use regular expressions.

JDK reinstalled several times, this version is needed

Comment: Does the same error occur if you add the import for java.util.regex manually?

Comment: yes, error left

Comment: Sorry, my NetBeans 8.2 and Java 8 function with Ctrl-O "Matcher", the regex Matcher followed by the nashorn one. So it must be something under the Windows user's AppData directory.

Comment: If you add the import manually, can you compile the class on the command line using `javac`?

Comment: You mean that after adding  `import java.util.regex.*;`  the error insists?

Comment: 1. When compiled with javac:
error: cannot find symbol
Matcher matcher;
symbol:   class Matcher
location: class Transformation

2. When adding import manually - classes Pattern, PatternSyntaxException and interface MatchResult are visible, and class Matcher - no

Comment: @McflonoMcfloonyloo Since you get the problem with javac as well as NetBeans then this is not a NetBeans issue; it is a JDK and/or path issue. It would be helpful to update the OP accordingly.

Comment: I deleted the JDK & JRE. I downloaded 1.8.0_112 from the Oracle website, and everything worked. I returning the version 1.8.0_111, and the error was no longer there. Miracles, and only